# Ask Pattern in Akka

Tags: scala, akka

I have a question regarding the Ask pattern in Akka.

I am calling an actor using the ask pattern from my application. My application is a normal class (not an actor itself):

```
(actor1Ref ? msg) mapTo[ResponseMsg]
```

However the actor which is called above calls a second actor like:

```
secondActor ! msg(sender)
```

and it's the second actor which returns the actual response like:

```
originalSender ! responseMsg
```

So basically there is an indirection involved and when Actor1 calls Actor2 it uses `!`.

I tested the code and it works. But I am not sure if the above is the right way of writing this code.

So should I always use `?` between the actor1 and actor2 calls and try to `pipeTo` the results? Or is it OK for me to use `!` between intermediate calls and when I want to return to the original caller, just send a message to the reference I pass around?

Comment: According to the documentation, it is okay: ActorRefs can be freely shared among actors by message passing. Please, check the documentation for more details http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/actor/ActorRef.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current approach is perfectly fine. In fact, it is preferable to use `tell` (`!`) for actor-to-actor communication. From the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/actors.html#send-messages):

> There are performance implications of using `ask` since something needs to keep track of when it times out, there needs to be something that bridges a `Promise` into an `ActorRef` and it also needs to be reachable through remoting. So always prefer `tell` for performance, and only `ask` if you must.
>
> [Tell] is the preferred way of sending messages. No blocking waiting for a message. This gives the best concurrency and scalability characteristics.